# How to see the "hidden" python built-in?

Tags: python

Some python built-in method (e.g. vars) are "hidden" by some identical local variable names. How to call the "hidden" built-in method?

I was in debug mode using `python -m pdb XXX.py`, and can't see the hidden built-in method (`vars`) in the `__builtins__` dictionary:

`(Pdb) dir(__builtins__)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault', 'update', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the special `__builtins__` module:

```
>>> __builtins__.vars
<built-in function vars>

>>> __builtins__.vars()
..ouput snipped..
```

If you're using the Python debugger (`python -m pdb script.py`), `__builtins__` seems to appear as `dict`, so use:

```
(Pdb) __builtins__['vars']
<built-in function vars>
```

Note that this is a *hack*, the 2 leading & trailing underscores are Python conventions for *"used internally, do not use in a script"*. Python gives you access to this anyway, but with this great power comes great responsibility, as it gives you the ability to do both very smart, *and* very stupid things!

---

Remember that in Python functions are like any other variables, so another way would be to save the previous `vars` function:

```
# No parens! We don't want to call the function, just assign it
>>> builtin_vars = vars
>>> vars = 'a string'
>>> builtin_vars
<built-in function vars>
>>> vars
'a string'
```

---

However, by far the best solution is to not overwrite these variables ;-) Most editors should highlight these, so you can easily recognize the most commonly overwritten ones (`vars`, `str`, `list`). Experience tells me that sooner or later you **will** be confused, and **will** cause hard-to-debug bugs, so just say "NO" ;-)

You can get a complete list of all these built-ins with the `dir()` function:

```
>>> dir(__builtins__)
```

Comment: I'd say [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) is a better idea because it's `useful in modules that provide objects with the same name as a built-in value, but in which the built-in of that name is also needed`